# Visual Studio 2013 Code Analysis Exception CA0055: Could not load assembly

Tags: visual-studio-2013, code-analysis

I am trying to run the Code analysis on Web Project in VS2013 but i am getting the exception CA0055.

I took a look at the log file. Here is the exception information which is getting logged.

```
<Exception Keyword="CA0055" Kind="AssemblyLoad">
<Type>Microsoft.FxCop.Common.AssemblyLoadException</Type>
<ExceptionMessage>Could not load MyProject.dll.</ExceptionMessage>
<InnerType>System.NullReferenceException</InnerType>
<InnerExceptionMessage>Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</InnerExceptionMessage>
         <InnerStackTrace>   at Phx.Metadata.ReaderImplementation.CreateTokenMap()
       at Phx.Metadata.MetadataLoader.GetModule(String fileName, FileInfo fileInfo, AssemblyUnit unit)
       at Phx.Metadata.MetadataLoader.GetAssembly(String fileName, AssemblyUnit unit)
       at Phx.Metadata.MetadataLoader.LoadAssemblyDefinition(AssemblyUnit unit)
       at Microsoft.FxCop.Engines.Phoenix.AssemblyLoader.ProcessWorklist(MetadataLoader metadataLoader, Boolean ignoreErrors)
       at Microsoft.FxCop.Engines.Phoenix.AssemblyLoader.LoadAttributeType(AggregateType type, MetadataLoader metadataLoader)
       at Microsoft.FxCop.Engines.Phoenix.AssemblyLoader.LoadAttributes(List`1 attributes, MetadataLoader metadataLoader)
       at Microsoft.FxCop.Engines.Phoenix.AssemblyLoader.LoadAttributes(ProgramUnit   programUnit, MetadataLoader metadataLoader)
             at Microsoft.FxCop.Engines.Phoenix.AssemblyLoader.LoadAssembly(String filePath)
       at Microsoft.FxCop.Engines.Phoenix.PhoenixAnalysisEngine.AnalyzeInternal()  
</InnerStackTrace>
</Exception>
```

Does any one came across the same type of issue?Any clue would be of great help.